# Is resistance of a 12V source down to 0.5V and 0.1mA even possible using E12 Series resistors?

Tags: led, resistors, resistance

I am stumped on this question out of my textbook, its about finding the value of a resistor for a circuit given the source voltage and device requirements in Volts and amps. In this case its 12V supply, for a meter that needs 0.5 V and 0.1 mA (that is 0.0001A) when I do the math to find the resistor value R, it is 115000 Ω . Then you have to select the appropriate Resistor from the E12 series (I don't know if that is just in Europe), the closest I can get is 120 kΩ which won't work because then the entire voltage would be lost or 100 kΩ which is far too small. Also the tolerance on these resistors is +/- 10%!! I look on youtube and only see examples of very easy to solve problems. I think I understand this but the answer won't fit the textbook, how would this problem be solved in reality? Thanks, first post :)

Comment: Yes it's possible, for example by combining resistors in series or parallel combinations. (And using higher tolerance resistors; 1% ones are cheap)

Comment: 120k is within 4.3% of the correct value, so if that's all the accuracy you need, just use it. If you want more accuracy, 115k is a standard 1% (E96) value.

Comment: In the context of your textbook, the device/meter cannot *force* 0.1mA to flow - so your statement that "120 kΩ which won't work because then the entire voltage would be lost" is incorrect. If you placed the 120k resistor in series with the device you would have 120k in series with 5k which, with a 12V source, will cause 96uA (0.096mA) to flow. That's only 4% different to your target 0.1mA - so if your textbook allows for a tolerance it might be good enough... Otherwise as others have written, you should consider series and/or parallel resistor combination to get to the exact 115k you need.

Comment: This could be done with only 2 resistors from the E12 set - in fact even E6 would give you the values you need.

Comment: Who even makes 10% tolerance resistors anymore? I've never encountered worse than 5%, and even that's going out of style these days in favor of 1%.

Comment: If the tolerance is 10% then that means even if you had a 115kΩ resistor, wouldn't it be too far away at the ends of its tolerance range?

Comment: Thank you @brhans. I forgot to calculate the 5k resistance for the meter! From the diagram and way the question is asked I will probably assume that the current to the meter is close enough to 0.1mA even if the 120k resistor is 10% off in either direction (I = 0.087mA - 0.106mA). Because it says "resistor" (singular) and up to this point in the book they haven't talked about parallel resistors. But yes as you and others said to be more exact two resistors in series would be a better solution.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say 3 resistors in series; 100k, 6.8k and 8.2k to give 115k...

Comment: 2 resistors: 15k is a standard value too.

Comment: Ah yes how did I not see that! you are right, thanks again!!